# Firebase Cloud Functions Deployment Error with error code "NoSuchKey"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy one of my functions from firebase CLI (version 8.12.1) and it keeps failing.
The function hasn't changed in weeks, so I am a bit confused as to why it's failing now.

**Error from the CLI**

> functions[http-api-(europe-west1)]: Deployment error.
> Build failed: Build error details not available. Please check the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=&advancedFilter=resource.type%3Dbuild%0Aresource.labels.build_id%3Dfeb2697d-29b4-4ab7-9b84-90d9f847be42%0AlogName%3Dprojects%2Fvestico-dev%2Flogs%2Fcloudbuild

**Logs from the cloud console**

> Step #3 - "restorer": Restoring data for "google.nodejs.functions-framework:functions-framework" from cache

> Step #3 - "restorer": \u001b[31;1mERROR: \u001b[0mfailed to restore: restoring data: GET https://storage.googleapis.com/eu.artifacts..appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:484d08dfc6a8f356c34a86fa4440fedf86f4fc398967eea66e4aab4e9ee81e3d?access_token=REDACTED: unsupported status code 404; body: `NoSuchKey`The specified key does not exist.No such object: eu.artifacts..appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:484d08dfc6a8f356c34a86fa4440fedf86f4fc398967eea66e4aab4e9ee81e3d

> Finished Step #3 - "restorer"

> ERROR: build step 3 "eu.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/nodejs10/builder:nodejs10_20201005_20_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 46

The interesting piece is probably the error from above:

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
  <Details>No such object: eu.artifacts.<project-id>.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:484d08dfc6a8f356c34a86fa4440fedf86f4fc398967eea66e4aab4e9ee81e3d</Details>
</Error>
```

What key is builder referring to? `<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` has accesss to the cloud function with roles `Cloud Functions Admin` and `Editor`.

#### EDIT

Deploying through `firebase deploy --only functions:<my-api>`

That function uses `@google-cloud/storage` to get a public url for a storage resource.

I'm loading the service account configs like this:

```js
const devServiceAccount = require("../../service-accounts/dev.json");
const prodServiceAccount = require("../../service-accounts/prod.json");

export const getAdminConfig = (): (AppOptions | undefined) => {
  const baseConfigEnv = process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG;
  if (!baseConfigEnv) {
    console.error("no firebase config environment");
    return undefined;
  }

  const app = functions.config().app;
  if (app === undefined) {
    console.error("no firebase app config");
    return undefined;
  }

  const serviceAccount = app.environment === 'dev' ? devServiceAccount : prodServiceAccount;
  const adminConfig = JSON.parse(baseConfigEnv) as AppOptions;
  adminConfig.credential = credential.cert(serviceAccount);

  return adminConfig;
}
```

The cloud storage is used here.

```js
const options = {
    action: 'read',
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 //1 hour
  } as GetSignedUrlConfig;

const file = bucket.file(path);
filePathPromises.push(file.getSignedUrl(options))
  });
```

My folder structure is as follows.

```
+ functions
  + lib
    + function.js
  + service-accounts
    + dev.json
    + prod.json
  + src
    + function.ts
```

I was ruling out that the service account files are the issue given that the files are loaded in `getAdminConfig()` for all functions in the project.

#### Update 10/13/20

I've verified the files uploaded to the GCF storage container. The JSON keys are there and in the right location. The paths match, so they *should* be found when the GCF is running.

Comment: Hi @bhr usually the `NoSuchKey` error is related to a file not exisiting in the system - in this case, related to your function. Considering that, could you please share the command you are using to deploy your functions and what this function should be doing?

Comment: @gso_grabriel: That's what I was thinking too. I'm not sure which file cannot be found though. I've added more context to the question above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a hint for the next soul running into this problem. It seems to be caused by missing/inaccessible file in the restore/rollback process.

I was successfully removing the problem by simply:

1. Deleting my functions using the web firebase console.
2. Deploying normally again `>firebase deploy`

Comment: I ran into the issue with another function again. This does the trick

Comment: I'm running into the NoSuchKey error when deploying with Google Cloud Functions after I created lifecycle delete rules for my container images. Do I need to delete my actual Cloud Functions? Wouldn't that break my app for any current users?

Comment: Yes, deleting your functions will temporarily break the functionality until the new deploy is finished. Sorry, I know of no other solution atm.
Did you delete old artifacts from your Firebase storage? The problem can be connected to that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there was an intermittent issue in Firebase Cloud Functions or GCF. I just ran `firebase deploy --only functions` again and it deployed successfully.

Comment: I have the same problem. Are you sure you did nothing but waited? :)

Comment: I just redeployed and it's working for me. Checked and couldn't find any changes related to the key files. Did deploying the function ever work for you?

Comment: Yes, worked a few days ago, now I cannot re-deploy same code but are running into above problem. :(